# How i use ObjectSet as parameter?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

```
using (var context = new JasminEntities())
{
    var expType = (from o in context.tblExpTypes where o.Id == lvExpType.FocusedItem.Text select o).Single();
        context.tblExpTypes.DeleteObject(expType);
        context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I have the above code and I need to just pass the context.tblExpTypes as argument b'cause in my project there are many forms which requires delete task, how I pass as parameter and then in function I will check that objectset to delete?

Answer (score 1):

What about generic approach:

```
public void Delete<T>(int someKey) where T : class, IEntity {
    var expType = context.CreateObjectSet<T>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == someKey);
    if (expType != null) {
       context.DeleteObject(expType);
       context.SaveChanges();
    } 
}
```

You must also ensure that every entity has `Id` property and that it implements interface `IEntity`:

```
public interface IEntity {
    int Id { get; }
}
```

Comment: now I need to call this function,    `var context = new JasminEntities();` and I have the entity in which I wants to update db, `context.tblExpTypes` or `context.tblUsers`, how can I call delete function for this, I tried like this `sMethod.Delete<Jasmin.tblExpType>(lvExpType.FocusedItem.Text);` but it gives an error.